# How to find point inside an ellipse?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, ellipse

I'm trying to find points inside the ellipse. It is not an 'ordinary' ellipse actually it is based on average and standard deviation which is much easier than calculating eigen values in order to find confidence interval

Function is not written by me here are the sources
https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/statistics/confidence_ellipse.html
https://carstenschelp.github.io/2018/09/14/Plot_Confidence_Ellipse_001.html

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

x = np.array([21.5,16.3,13.7,20.0,17.4,10.4,16.9,7.0,13.8,15.2,13.8,8.2,18.0,9.4,13.2,7.2,21.2,30.2,13.5,29.8,18.3,20.2,31.1,21.5,29.8,18.0,13.1,24.1,32.5,15.4,16.1,15.0,25.9,3.0,17.0,23.6,17.6,-11.8,22.2,26.6,17.8,20.6,23.0,28.0,25.3,22.1,22.4,16.3,22.0,12.1])
y = np.array([92.4,98.2,97.6,95.9,96.5,92.1,89.6,89.4,89.2,89.4,90.2,86.7,89.5,89.9,90.2,87.6,104.0,87.3,99.4,85.4,92.8,92.0,87.9,96.2,94.1,95.2,95.6,86.3,87.6,89.5,95.0,97.1,93.0,87.8,98.9,98.2,100.1,45.4,92.1,91.6,94.7,93.9,91.4,91.1,95.7,93.8,96.4,94.1,94.0,89.1])

#function obtained from matplotlib documentation
#https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/statistics/confidence_ellipse.html

def confidence_ellipse(x, y, ax, n_std=3.0, facecolor='none', **kwargs):
    """
    Create a plot of the covariance confidence ellipse of *x* and *y*.
    Parameters
    ----------
    x, y : array-like, shape (n, )
        Input data.
    ax : matplotlib.axes.Axes
        The axes object to draw the ellipse into.
    n_std : float
        The number of standard deviations to determine the ellipse's radiuses.
    **kwargs
        Forwarded to `~matplotlib.patches.Ellipse`
    Returns
    -------
    matplotlib.patches.Ellipse
    """
    if x.size != y.size:
        raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")

    cov = np.cov(x, y)
    pearson = cov[0, 1]/np.sqrt(cov[0, 0] * cov[1, 1])
    # Using a special case to obtain the eigenvalues of this
    # two-dimensionl dataset.
    ell_radius_x = np.sqrt(1 + pearson)
    ell_radius_y = np.sqrt(1 - pearson)
    ellipse = Ellipse((0, 0), width=ell_radius_x * 2, height=ell_radius_y * 2,
                      facecolor=facecolor, **kwargs)

    # Calculating the stdandard deviation of x from
    # the squareroot of the variance and multiplying
    # with the given number of standard deviations.
    scale_x = np.sqrt(cov[0, 0]) * n_std
    mean_x = np.mean(x)

    # calculating the stdandard deviation of y ...
    scale_y = np.sqrt(cov[1, 1]) * n_std
    mean_y = np.mean(y)

    transf = transforms.Affine2D() \
        .rotate_deg(45) \
        .scale(scale_x, scale_y) \
        .translate(mean_x, mean_y)

    ellipse.set_transform(transf + ax.transData)
    return ax.add_patch(ellipse)


#implementation
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 4))
ax.scatter(x,y,s=5)
ellipse = confidence_ellipse(x,y,ax,n_std=2,edgecolor='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: Output visual]

Afterwards I tried to find get center coordinates and the points inside the ellipse as below:

```
ellipse.get_center()
Out:(0,0)
ellipse.contains_point([21.5,92.4])#first points in x,y arrays
Out:False
ellipse.contains_point([0,0])#get_center() result
Out:False
```

Ellipse plot is working fine but I need every points coordinates inside the ellipse.
What I am doing wrong? I already checked similar questions but they didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confidence_ellipse example function only returns an object for drawing, and the contains point will only tell you if the point is on the ellipse.

What you probably want is something like:

```
import math
class distribution():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.cov  = np.cov(x, y)        
        self.mean = np.matrix( [np.mean(x), np.mean(y)])
    def dist(self, x,y):
        tmp = np.matrix([x,y])
        diff = self.mean - tmp
        dist = diff * np.linalg.inv(self.cov) * diff.T
        return math.sqrt(dist)
    def is_inside(self, x,y,nstd=2.0):
    if (self.dist(x,y) < nstd):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then you can do :

```
d = distribution(x,y)    
d.is_inside(24.1,86.3)
```

Returns true.

Then, for all the points:

```
points = np.array(list(zip(x, y)))

points_in  = list(filter(lambda p: d.is_inside(p[0],p[1]), points))
points_out =  list(filter(lambda p: not d.is_inside(p[0],p[1]), points))
x_in = [ x[0] for x in points_in] 
y_in = [ x[1] for x in points_in] 

x_out = [ x[0] for x in points_out] 
y_out = [ x[1] for x in points_out] 


fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 8))
ax2.scatter(x_in,y_in,s=5, facecolor="green")
ax2.scatter(x_out,y_out, s=5, facecolor="red")
ellipse = confidence_ellipse(x,y,ax2,n_std=2,edgecolor='red') # this presupposes that you still have the confidence_ellipse still defined

plt.show()
```

And your output should look something like this:
[image]
Where the red points are more than 2 standard deviations away, and the green ones are inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot all the `x,y` label on the plot.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

x = np.array([21.5,16.3,13.7,20.0,17.4,10.4,16.9,7.0,13.8,15.2,13.8,8.2,18.0,9.4,13.2,7.2,21.2,30.2,13.5,29.8,18.3,20.2,31.1,21.5,29.8,18.0,13.1,24.1,32.5,15.4,16.1,15.0,25.9,3.0,17.0,23.6,17.6,-11.8,22.2,26.6,17.8,20.6,23.0,28.0,25.3,22.1,22.4,16.3,22.0,12.1])
y = np.array([92.4,98.2,97.6,95.9,96.5,92.1,89.6,89.4,89.2,89.4,90.2,86.7,89.5,89.9,90.2,87.6,104.0,87.3,99.4,85.4,92.8,92.0,87.9,96.2,94.1,95.2,95.6,86.3,87.6,89.5,95.0,97.1,93.0,87.8,98.9,98.2,100.1,45.4,92.1,91.6,94.7,93.9,91.4,91.1,95.7,93.8,96.4,94.1,94.0,89.1])

#function obtained from matplotlib documentation
#https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/statistics/confidence_ellipse.html

def confidence_ellipse(x, y, ax, n_std=3.0, facecolor='none', **kwargs):
    """
    Create a plot of the covariance confidence ellipse of *x* and *y*.
    Parameters
    ----------
    x, y : array-like, shape (n, )
        Input data.
    ax : matplotlib.axes.Axes
        The axes object to draw the ellipse into.
    n_std : float
        The number of standard deviations to determine the ellipse's radiuses.
    **kwargs
        Forwarded to `~matplotlib.patches.Ellipse`
    Returns
    -------
    matplotlib.patches.Ellipse
    """
    if x.size != y.size:
        raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")

    cov = np.cov(x, y)
    pearson = cov[0, 1]/np.sqrt(cov[0, 0] * cov[1, 1])
    # Using a special case to obtain the eigenvalues of this
    # two-dimensionl dataset.
    ell_radius_x = np.sqrt(1 + pearson)
    ell_radius_y = np.sqrt(1 - pearson)
    ellipse = Ellipse((0, 0), width=ell_radius_x * 2, height=ell_radius_y * 2,
                      facecolor=facecolor, **kwargs)

    # Calculating the stdandard deviation of x from
    # the squareroot of the variance and multiplying
    # with the given number of standard deviations.
    scale_x = np.sqrt(cov[0, 0]) * n_std
    mean_x = np.mean(x)

    # calculating the stdandard deviation of y ...
    scale_y = np.sqrt(cov[1, 1]) * n_std
    mean_y = np.mean(y)

    transf = transforms.Affine2D() \
        .rotate_deg(45) \
        .scale(scale_x, scale_y) \
        .translate(mean_x, mean_y)

    ellipse.set_transform(transf + ax.transData)
    return ax.add_patch(ellipse)


#implementation
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 8))
ax.scatter(x,y,s=15)
ellipse = confidence_ellipse(x,y,ax,n_std=2,edgecolor='red')

# zip joins x and y coordinates in pairs
for x,y in zip(x,y):

    label = f"({x},{y})"
    #label = "{:.2f}".format(y) # plot just y-value of the point
    # print(label) # uncomment if you want to print the points for reference 
    plt.annotate(label, # this is the text
                 (x,y), # this is the point to label
                 textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
                 xytext=(0,10), # distance from text to points (x,y)
                 ha='center') # horizontal alignment can be left, right or center
              
plt.show()
```

[image]

**P.S.** : You need to adjust your `xytext` accordingly. That is just the point where this `label` has plotted in the figure.

You can also `print` those values for your reference. Just put `print(label)` and it will print all the points for you.

```sh
(21.5,92.4)
(16.3,98.2)
(13.7,97.6)
(20.0,95.9)
(17.4,96.5)
(10.4,92.1)
(16.9,89.6)
(7.0,89.4)
(13.8,89.2)
(15.2,89.4)
(13.8,90.2)
(8.2,86.7)
(18.0,89.5)
(9.4,89.9)
(13.2,90.2)
(7.2,87.6)
(21.2,104.0)
(30.2,87.3)
(13.5,99.4)
(29.8,85.4)
(18.3,92.8)
(20.2,92.0)
(31.1,87.9)
(21.5,96.2)
(29.8,94.1)
(18.0,95.2)
(13.1,95.6)
(24.1,86.3)
(32.5,87.6)
(15.4,89.5)
(16.1,95.0)
(15.0,97.1)
(25.9,93.0)
(3.0,87.8)
(17.0,98.9)
(23.6,98.2)
(17.6,100.1)
(-11.8,45.4)
(22.2,92.1)
(26.6,91.6)
(17.8,94.7)
(20.6,93.9)
(23.0,91.4)
(28.0,91.1)
(25.3,95.7)
(22.1,93.8)
(22.4,96.4)
(16.3,94.1)
(22.0,94.0)
(12.1,89.1)
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but actually I was looking 'filtering' operation for ellipse inside.